# Safely check if an EJB exists or prevent rollback if it doesn't

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have some cleanup code which may try to refer to an (stateful) EJB that doesn't exist. For example:

```
try{
    //In my case ejb is actually a delegate. Not sure this makes a difference
    ejb.doSomeMethod();
}catch(NoSuchEJBException nsejb){
    //Deal with this but continue
}
```

However the NoSuchEJBException is causing a transaction rollback.
Is there a way to prevent the rollback or to check if `ejb` no longer exists?

Comment: What would cause the EJB not to exist? Are you undeploying them at runtime?

Comment: It's a session ejb (in this case a cart). They may have died from throwing a runtime or having been abandoned and destroyed by the container.

Comment: I assume you're accessing the ejb's using the `@EJB` annotation. If so, they normally shouldn't be removed by the container in case of exceptions etc. And even if so, the container should create a new instance whenever you try to access those ejbs/proxies.

Comment: The carts are created programmatically when a web user needs one and these are then stored. If the cart is abandoned (and is eventually destroyed by the container) or there is an unexpected exception then then the handle stored will throw a NoSuchEJBException when any method is invoked on it.

Comment: Hmm, you are talking about stateful session beans, aren't you?

Comment: Yeah, sorry should have made that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could run that code in a new transaction which then gets rolled back but won't affect the outer transaction.

Comment: Looks like this is the only option.